Packaged app throws an error "edge.initializeClrFunc is not a function"
Im using electron-edge-js and a c# dll I made myself.
Im packaging my electron app using electron-builder and when I ship this to other devices and run it, i get this error:
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: edge.initializeClrFunc is not a function
at exports.func
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1391:14)
at Module._extensions.js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1451:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1214:32)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1030:12)
at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13672)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1242:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
at Object.<anonymous>

The error is in "myapp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app\node_modules\electron-edge-js\lib\edge.js" file where it returns edge.initializeClrFunc(options)
I have tried building the app with "asar":false and "asar": true and I still get the same problem.
Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?
